# how to a show view in angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to show a view using anonymous  route js .Actually I saw a good developer code he always make anonymous  class of route and controller .I need to know how he move to view example I make route.js file  as he dis for first view ( it show "first page").But why it not display on my view .He also make anonymous  controller js for each view .Could you please tell me where I am doing wrong .

here is my plunker 
http://plnkr.co/edit/kXJV11B0Bi8XV2nwMXLt

```
   (function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('a.app')
        .config(Routes);




    Routes.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];
    function Routes($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        // Default
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app');
        // Application
        $stateProvider
            .state('app', {
                url: '/app',
                abstract: true,
                templateUrl: 'first.html',

            });
    }

})();
```

Comment: any update of this Question ..any one have any idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed couple of problems:

- Restangular is not defined - it's not included.
- Named view in index.html: `<div ui-view="app"></div>`
- `DEFAULT_ROUTE` also was not included, so injector were throwing an error.
- Changed route configuration to `{ url: '/app', views: { app: { templateUrl: 'first.html' } } }`
- Changed the line: `.module('eztrackit.app')` in `route.js` with `.module('firstApp')`, as you're configuring `firstApp`, not `eztrackit.app`.

And now it's [working](http://plnkr.co/edit/OOUCswgzZaMdMlyBi4hH?p=preview).